# how to run npm commands using cmake

Tags: npm, cmake

I've got Karma set up in a subd_app dir. The testing is set up so that if I run "npm install" and then "npm test" from sub_app, Karma will run successfully.  The challenge is that the main directory and all subdirs are written in C/Cpp and we use Cmake to do the make/build from the main dir. How do I incorporate the two npm commands so that they are executed when I run cmake and make all?

```
Example:
main_dir/
    main.c
    some other c and cpp files
    CMakelists.txt
    sub_dir/
        other.c
        CMakelists.txt
        some other c and cpp files
    sub_app/
        js and html files
        package.json
        karma.conf.js
```

Comment: During `cmake` programs can be executed with [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/execute_process.html) command. During `make` programs can be executed with [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_custom_target.html).

Comment: This worked! thanks